# two IDE and 1 android sdk manager, is it conflict free?

Tags: android, eclipse, ide

two IDE and 1 android sdk manager, is it conflict free? Yes, concerning my two IDE using the same android sdk manager.. do i need to worry about conflicts or something?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that should worry you. You have just one signature which is created by the Android SDK build tools. So you can develop on the same phone from both of them. If you run the same app from boths IDE then the last to run would overwrite the other.